# Influence of tiling image size on page rendering speed

Tags: iphone, html, performance, rendering

If a background image is tiled, do the dimensions of the image file have any influence on page rendering speed?

I imagine that the smaller the image, the more blits have to be performed to fill the target area, so the longer the page will take to render[1]. Do you suppose this is true?

I'm asking mostly from the perspective of the iPhone (so Mobile Safari), since that's what I'm trying to optimize a site for.

[1] If that is really the case, the typical "empty.gif" (1x1 transparent image) would be a real performance killer.

Comment: also in the case of 1x1 image, there isn't much maths going on to work out pixel relativity ... just the copying of an (A)RGB value across another matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do any performance optimization without really knowing what's going on or doing any field tests.

There's much less memory involved when tiling using a small image, so the CPU's cache is always hit, which could mean much higher performance.

Answer (score 0):

Althought true, most rendering systems will be able to render a repetition of 1x1 px fairly fast due to the fact that it boils down to:

1. Repetition of a value stored in memory/cache, to another memory value
2. OR, operations on a graphics subsystem (such as OpenGL) which have operations for this on the faster memory of the GPU hardware (GDDR or whatver)

It would be more computationally expensive to tile a 50x50px image over a 5000x5000 area than it would to map a 1x1 pixel image over a 100x100 area because there is more data involved.

I wouldn't worry too much about the mechanics, just decide if you can perform it **fast enough**

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a measurable difference, at least as long as we are not talking about images 1000×1000 pixels. But as Nikolai said, you have to measure. This is exactly the case where nothing beats an experiment.